# Angular 4 throwing error EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream" after migrating to .NetCore 2.0

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an existing SPA based on Asp .Net Core (I was using Yo generator-aspnetcore-spa to generate a template). It worked perfectly fine, but after migration to .NetCore 2.0 it started to throw the error:

> EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not
>   "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.

As I understood this problem affects only auto-refresh after updating any file (hot module replacement as far as I know). All other stuff is working fine.

So, the question is how to fix the error above?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution, mainly the problem is in .NetCore routing system, it is taking over and trying to handle the request, returning text/html, so it's sending the actual webpack_hmr hot file. To fix it you need to edit **Configure** method in the **Startup.cs** file.

1. Before:

   ```
   // some code
   app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
               HotModuleReplacement = true                    
           });
   //some code
   ```
2. After:

   ```
   // some code
   app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
               HotModuleReplacement = true,
               HotModuleReplacementEndpoint = "/dist/__webpack_hmr"                   
           });
   // some code
   ```

The solution is taken from this [thread on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1204)

Comment: @Serg.ID, what a pain in the ass. HMR has been broken since the upgrade to 2.0

Comment: I need to play with the endpoint more but this was definitely the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Try Changing the hosting environment from Production to Development

1. Check whether your **Hosting environment** is set to **Production** or to **Development** (Webpack HMR is disabled for Production)
   [image: Hosting Env is in Production]
2. Change the Hosting environment to Development.

   Add `export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=development` to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` file.

   Follow the [link](http://szumiato.pl/2017/06/29/asp-net-core-javascriptservices-problem-with-eventsource-mime-type/) for more exhaustive explanation.

   Thus your output should be:
   [image: Hosting environment is not Development]

This [link](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/) explains how to change the env in more depth.

Comment: The problem existed for the development environment. Everything was working before migration to .net core 2

Comment: I tried your your answer and it didn't work. Then the link at my 2nd point fixed my error. The problem was my hosting env.

Comment: From this point of view you are absolutely right, HMR works only in Dev env. However, this quetion was about “EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html")” error

Comment: You're right! this the same error I also got but my problem was different I guess, and I was able to resolve it by changing the Hosting env.

Comment: @Serg.ID Still Unable to figure out this. After deployed, our env is not Dev then how to handle this issue? there it won't use any HMR.

Comment: HMR won't work in Production mode, it(HMR) is advised to be disabled in production mode. (if I understand your issue)